# Postfix Sending Email From Development Machine

Tags: postfix-mta

I've got postfix setup and running on my production server. Rather than installing another copy on my dev machine i'd like to just use the production server to send email in testing, but i'm getting "Relay access denied" errors. How do I configure postfix to allow outgoing mail from a different (my specific machine, not just any random ip of course) machine?

Does it have something to do with the relayhost param in main.cf? If so what do I add there? Any other settings need to be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add my local ip to the mynetworks param.

```
mynetworks = a.b.c.d, .e.f.g.h
```

I was getting confused about using relay instead. Apparently relay is to tell postfix to use a different ip to send messages. What I needed was to tell it to accept outgoing from a different ip.